# json encode for following array

Tags: php, json

i have following array . i want to json_encode for this array Result  like `[{"dietary_options":"234"},{"dietary_options":"123"}]` using array method not for loop.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [dietary_options] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [dietary_options] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [dietary_options] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [dietary_options] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [dietary_options] =>234 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [dietary_options] => 123
    )
```

)

Comment: and why is it that you can't use a `for` or a `foreach`? it just takes a few lines using them

Comment: json_encode($my_array);

Comment: Take a look at array_filter

Comment: first priority to using array function . i already done with for loop but it is good if using array function.

Comment: @SvenLiivak no its not working its return null too. i dont want that .

Comment: hey, try my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
 $data = array(array('dietary_options'=>''),
                  array('dietary_options'=>'one'),
                 array('dietary_options'=>'two'));


$data = array_map('array_filter', $data);
$data = array_values(array_filter($data));
print_r(json_encode($data,true));
// print_r(json_encode(array_filter($data),true));
```

Comment: Thanks Work for me but u don't need to be write array_filter in json_encode 
      print_r(json_encode($data,true)); @kmg kumar

Answer (score 1):

Simply array_filter is the easy way

```
$data = json_encode(array_filter($data, function ($item) { 
    return !!$item['dietary_options'];
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this . It's working as your expecting format without loop.

```
$array=array(
array("dietary_options"=>"234"),
array("dietary_options"=>""),
array("dietary_options"=>""),
array("dietary_options"=>"123")
);

$array_data = array_map('array_filter', $array);
$array_data = array_filter($array_data);
$array_data = array_values($array_data);
print_r(json_encode($array_data));
```

Comment: hey, did you check your code ?, they gives the object in json value.

Comment: {"5":{"dietary_options":"234"},"7":{"dietary_options":"123"}} i got this kind of result  i want  [{"dietary_options":"234"},{"dietary_options":"123"}] .. BTW thanks ...  @VinothRaja

Comment: Hi @Kanewilliam , could you explain what the different between VinothRaja and Kmg kumar answer ?

Answer (score 0):

please try below code.

```
$data = array(array("dietary_options"=>""),array("dietary_options"=>"789"),array("dietary_options"=>"123456"));
$data = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $data));

echo json_encode(array_values($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me,

```
print_r(json_encode(array_filter($myArray)));
```

Answer (score 0):

php array_filter good option.

```
$data = array(
            array("dietary_options" => ''),
            array("dietary_options" => ''),
            array("dietary_options" => ''),
            array("dietary_options" => 123),
            array("dietary_options" => 234),
        );
return new JsonResponse(array_values(array_filter($data, function($k){
        return !!$k["dietary_options"];
})));
```